# How to get the response object of an ajax request with laravel?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, fetch

Guys I'm making a fetch request for laravel without using jquery and I would like to get the return of this request, however when I give a `console.log()` in the response the console informs `undefined`.

This is my request:

```
fetch(action, {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "X-CSRF-Token": token
    },
    method: "post",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password
    })
})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This is my controller that returns the empty field information:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (in_array('', $request->only('email', 'password'))) {
        $json['message'] = "Empty";
        return response()->json($json);
    }

    var_dump($request->all());
}
```

The request was successful and the browser informs the response message:

[Object response message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BEBm.png)

However `console.log(data)` returns `undefined`, how can I return the object that contains the message?

Taking advantage of the question, is this the best way to make this request?

Thank you guys

Comment: maybe you should use `json_encode` in your php before returning the value\

Comment: Try `console.log(response)` in your first `then` statement instead of `response.json()`

Comment: It doesn't work returning json_encode and console the response from the first `then`